# Django rest auth store token securely

Tags: reactjs, django, security, authentication, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to implement authentication with django-rest-auth library in the backend and I'm using react for the front-end. Django-rest-auth returns a token after authentication and I was guessing how to handle it.

- From a security perspective can that token be saved in an HTTPOnly cookie or it should be kept only in memory?
- Exists a tested approach to achieve local persistence with django-rest-auth and react without implementing vulnerabilities in the website?

Comment: Hi Andrea. Are you serve your frontend code from one endpoint and then fetch dynamic data from Django rest api browserside and want on subsequent reload not to reauthorize?

Comment: Actually, I'm serving the front-end directly in Django using the build folder. And yes, I don't want to reauthorize on subsequent reloads since it will ruin my user experience

Comment: Do you realize, that your approach make it impossible to make any SEO on your site and leave it invisible for crawlers? I’m sorry for this question, I ask because I got this situation by myself ;)

Comment: And yes, they say that it’s dangerous to persist in LocalStorage, but in almost all tutorials they does use it for token’s persistence.

Comment: Thanks for the hint dmitriy. Have you any suggestion on how to improve this behaviour? For now it’s not a major concern but later I will need to fix this

Comment: Yes, I have. Moreover, if SEO matters for you, I strongly recommend that you choose different approach, because it would be very difficult to make later. It’s architectural decision. 
I’ve spent a lot of time to dig into exactly that stack - React on the front and Django on the back. 
So my suggestion is as follows:

Comment: Can’t edit comment. Can send you email with suggestions if you want

Comment: I strongly recommend you use GraphQL instead of REST. it’s amazing expirience. Particularly- FormidableURQL on the front and Django Graphene on the back. It’s absolutely amazing experience. Ways ways simpler than REST

Comment: Thanks, I will dig deeper into that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every method of storing token on the client-side has some weakness:

- storing the token in HTTPOnly cookie makes the application vulnerable to CSRF attack
- storing the token in localStorage makes the application vulnerable to XSS attack

I'm personally using the localStorage to store token because it is convenient. React has built-in XSS prevention and you can additionally switch on CSP (Content Security Protection).  I write the article about my approach: https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/ - the httpOnly vs localStorage discussion is at the end of the post. There is also full tutorial how to start SaaS app with Django and React ([link](https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/)).

Comment: For what concerns CSRF attack I was considering putting up both a CSRF token and a CORS policy to avoid it being exploited. However, I was considering local storage as the worst choice.

Comment: I am very confused, in some pages they strongly recommend not to use localStorage